# ImageViews set programmatically do not appear

Tags: android, arrays, dimensional

I have a 2-dim. array of ImageViews. They are set to a RelativeLayout programmatically. But when I start the App, they simply don't appear.
This is my code:

```
private void setMap(ImageView[][] fields){
    RelativeLayout relLay = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.screen);
    OnClickListener listener = new MyOnClickListener();
    for (int i = 0; i < numFieldsHeight; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < numFieldsWidth; j++){
            ImageView img = new ImageView(MapActivity.this);
            img.setImageResource(R.drawable.map);
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            if (j != 0)
                params.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, fields[i][j-1].getId());
            else
                params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
            if (i != 0)
                params.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, fields[i-1][j].getId());
            else
                params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
            params.height = fieldLength;
            params.width = fieldLength;
            img.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            img.setId(getFieldId(j,i));
            img.setOnClickListener(listener);
            fields[i][j] = img;
            relLay.addView(fields[i][j], params);
        }
    }
}
```

and

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#000000" >

    <RelativeLayout 
        android:id="@+id/relLayDiffSeekBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        ...

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/screen"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="#222222" >

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Further attributes of the RelativeLayout "screen" are set in code.
But this works, I can see the RelativeLayout, just the ImageViews are missing.

There are no Exceptions thrown. Please help me!

------! Edit !------

I am very sorry, this code is actually working. The problem was that I forgot to set the variable fieldLength to something different from 0.
Thank you very much for your help anyway! :)

Comment: What Layout do you want to have? This seems like a GridView so why aren't you using a GridView? Perhaps a relLay.invalidate() will show the added Images.

Comment: post a XML of the Activity please

Comment: invalidate() does not help

Answer (score 0):

```
Drawable d = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.map);
d.setBounds(0, 0, 50, 50);
img.setImageDrawable(d);
```

Comment: unfortunately this does not change anything

Answer (score 0):

```
public void horizontalScrollGalleryLayout () {
    sv=new HorizontalScrollView(this);
    LinearLayout llh = new LinearLayout(this);
    llh.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParamsTV = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(90,90);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParamsLL = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParamsLLD = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    layoutParamsTV.setMargins(10, 5, 5, 5);
    for(int k=0;k<6;k++)
    {   
        LinearLayout llv = new LinearLayout(this);
        for (int i=0; i<4; i++) {
            llv.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
            img=new ImageButton(this);
            try {
                img.setBackgroundResource(integerIDs[total]);
            } catch (Exception e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            llv.addView(img, layoutParamsTV);
        }
        llh.addView(llv, layoutParamsLL);
        llh.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    }
    sv.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
    sv.addView(llh, layoutParamsLLD);
    setContentView(sv);

}
```

This could be one of the Solution...for creating a grid of Matrix 
for you problem .try it...any problem let me know

Comment: I tried this, but still same problem. I changed all ImageViews to Buttons and tried your code with it, but I still cannot see them.

Comment: check out the edit one this will create a Dynamic Scrolable matrix of  grid 6*4

Comment: actually I do not want to use a GridView. This is quite complicated for what I want. I need a field of a non changing number of quadratic buttons that are placed next to each other without spaces between them. This field may not be scrollable, every button must be visible and must stay in the same place all the time. I want it to look like a single picture, but every button must be colored and clicked independently.